# Apache Mina SFTP 2.0.0 Upgrade

Tags: sftp, sshd, apache-mina

I am trying to upgrade my 0.13.0 sshd-core and sshd-sftp to 2.1.0. But there is huge implementation change. Any one using latest versions that supports SFTP protocol 6.0. I see FileSystemView Class and sftplet package is not available.

Comment: HI @RanjithMRK, did you upgrade sshd-core, now i am trying to do the same.

Comment: Yes @DecKno. Upgrade after few trial and errors. let me know if there is anything i could do about it

Comment: @RanjithMRK can you please share what have you used to replace `sftplet` with latest version to validate request and file size?

Answer (score 0):

Extend the SftpSubsystem and force to use protocol 3.0.

```
public class MySftpSubsystem extends SftpSubsystem {
@Override
protected Reply doProcess(Request request) throws IOException {

    if (request instanceof SshFxpInitRequest) {
        SshFxpInitRequest sshFxpInitRequest = (SshFxpInitRequest) request;
        request = (Request)(new SshFxpInitRequest(3));

    } 

}
```